# Form post adding data in url

Tags: html, forms, post, clean-urls

I have some strange thing happening from my self post forms.  I thought using form method="post" would not put data in the url.  And I'm having different outcomes on both forms

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            some junk
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea id="summernote" name="Full_Discription" class="form-control" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type='hidden' name='var' value='<?php echo "$Known_Issue_id";?>'/> 
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-accent">Submit Follow-up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If I submit this form the hidden data shows in URL but not the body text from summernot
web_known_issues_bug.php?bug=20

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>Website Issue Type:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="Issue_Plugin" id="Issue_Plugin" required>
                <option value="">- Select Web Issue -</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <label>Description Of Known Issue:</label> <input name="Issue_Discription" type="text" value="" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>Type Of Issue:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="Issue_Type" id="Issue_Type" required>
                <option value="">- Bug Type -</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label>Submit Issue</label><BR>
            <input type='hidden' name='bug' value='<?php echo "none";?>'/> 
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-accent">Submit Issue</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <textarea id="summernote" name="Full_Discription" class="form-control" required><?php echo $SendBody; ?></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

This form is spitting everything to the url?
web_known_issues.php?message=Added%20New%20Bug%20List%20Item&title=Siclone%20Crashes%20when%20not%20used%20everyday&full=asdasdasdasdasd

I really need this stuff to send clean urls.  Any idea on what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is solved. My error, I left in some debug code in the miles of PHP